# Raspberry Pi - Doorbell using server side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to create a server side doorbell that triggers from an https call.  I have this running on a Raspberry Pi B+ running Raspberry Pi OS lite.  I've tested aplay and it works, and all the files are in their appropriate places.

Here is the Javascript I'm using:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/play-sound', (req, res) => {
  // Execute a command to play a sound (you can replace this with your own sound file and player command)
  exec('aplay /usr/share/sounds/alsa/doorbell.wav', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
      return res.status(500).send('Error playing sound');
    }
    console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
    res.send('Sound played successfully');
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});
```

and HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Play Sound</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="playSound">Play Sound</button>

  <script>
    const playButton = document.getElementById('playSound');

    playButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('https://10.8.8.109:3000/play-sound', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        });

        if (response.ok) {
          alert('Sound played successfully');
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to play sound');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert('An error occurred while playing the sound');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I go to the page and press the button I get "An error occurred while playing the sound"

So the script is running, I just can't seem to figure out why it's not executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

I think we might be missing a bit more necessary information. For instance, what was the content of the response? What status did it return?

That being said, you are making your call to `https`, and unless you have a much more complicated setup than you are showing here (nginx, letsencrypt + certs), you most likely need to be making your call to plain old `http`

Comment: Thanks for you reply.  I have tested http and I got the same result.  Upon further testing in the browser console I see that I'm getting 'connection refused'.  When I do a netstat it shows the port open but only for tcp6.  If I can figure out how to open the port on tcp I can  see if that is indeed the issue.

Comment: Ah then that definitely sounds like the problem. Make sure the port is open and definitely make your requests to http rather than https. Good luck!

Comment: I don't think the issue is with node here. According to https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#serverlisten by default, `listen()` works on both ipv4 and ipv6. I believe the issue is most likely with your firewall rules. I have probably 40+ different apps I host across several servers here at home and have never seen Node default to only listen on ipv6